# ¿Cómo usar función mail() en el SiteController de yii1 en php?

Tags: php, yii, mail

soy nuevo en PHP y estoy usando el Framework Yii1.
Tengo el siguiente código HTML que usaré para implementar una pestaña de Contacto:

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s6 l10">
  <label for="nombre">Nombre Completo</label>
  <input id="nombre" type="text" class="validate">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s6 l10">
  <label for="email">Dirección de correo</label>
  <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s6 l10">
  <label for="asunto">Asunto</label>
  <input id="asunto" type="text" class="validate">
 </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="input-field col s6 l10">
  <label for="mensaje">Mensaje</label>
  <input id="mensaje" type="text" class="validate">
 </div><br>
</div>

<div class="row">
 <a href="#">Enviar mensaje</a>   
</div>
```

Entonces, mi consulta es la siguiente: 
¿Cómo uso la función mail() en mi "SiteController.php" para obtener los datos de ese fragmento de código HTML?

Estaré atento a cualquier ayuda y/o sugerencia, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En los inputs coloca el name, para a posteriorí agarrar con php los elementos de cada input.

Por ejemplo:

**Tu tienes:**

```
  <input id="email" type="text" class="validate">
```

**Coloca el name = " "  a cada input:**

```
 <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="validate">
```

En el boton de envíar te acosejo que coloques un input de tipo submit para despues tomar la acción con php.

Ejemplo:

```
<input  name"enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje">
```

**Despues con php agarras cada name = " ", vendría a ser algo así:**

```
<?php

  if (isset($_POST['enviar'])) {

    if (!empty($_POST['nombre']) 
    && !empty($_POST['asunto'])  
    && !empty($_POST['email']) 
    && !empty($_POST['mensaje'])) {

        // Llamando a los campos
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];

        // Correo del destinatario/Comerciante
        $destinatario = "youemail@noreply.com";

        /* Imprime los datos en el body de el correo con etiquetas HTML5 y CSS3
        Y el logotipo */
        $carta = "<img src='http://youwebsite/imgs/logo.png'><br>";
        $carta .= "<b style='color:#173B59'>Nombre:</b> <span style='color:#3683C5'>$nombre</span><br>";
        $carta .= "<b style='color:#173B59'>Asunto:</b> <span style='color:#3683C5'>$asunto</span><br>";
        $carta .= "<b style='color:#173B59'>Email:</b> $email<br>";
        $carta .= "<b style='color:#173B59'>Mensaje:</b><br><span style='color:#3683C5'>$mensaje</span>";

        //Datos de quien envía, recibe y para quien va dirigido el correo
        $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-utf-8' . "\r\n".
        $headers .= 'From: noreply@youemail.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To:'.$email. "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();´


        //enviando mensaje
        $mail = mail($destinatario,$asunto,$carta,$headers);

        if ($mail) {
          echo 'Correo enviado con exito';
        }else{
          echo 'Error al envíar el correo';
      }
    }
  }

?>
```

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Antonio, voy a probar esto :)

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @FranciscoVargas? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!